# синхронизация хмл файлов

Tags: xml, синхронизация

есть несколько хмл файлов на серверах поставщиков. Можно ли сделать их автоматическую закачку? или скрипт, который будет запускать их закачку. В идеале - появляется эксель файл, который синхронизируется каждый день с одним из поставщиков. Как такое можно реализовать? Пытался парсить через гугл spreadsheets, но в итоге он захлебнулся от количества запросов.

Comment: Непонятно куда закачку, для чего, с чем синхронизировать, какой формат нужен, подробнее опишите проблему

Comment: на компьютер, для сверки новых цен, самого себя, эксель